# onEngineListener returns UNKNOWN error in android 6.0

Tags: android, here-api

This error did not happen in android 5, but now that I am testing my app on android 6, the `onEngineListener` always returns an `UNKNOWN` error. I have the latest version of the HERE-maps SDK (3.1.1), and I am also checking [permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

How can I get the mapEngine to be initialized ? (I insist on the fact that it was working great on android 5)

**EDIT :** I was trying on my Xperia Z3 Compact, with Android 6.0.1 and I got the `UNKNOWN` error, but I have tried on a LG G4 which has Android 6.0 (I don't think there is a major difference between 6.0 and 6.0.1) and it worked well.

It could be a device problem but it seems weird because the app worked well on my Xperia when it had Android 5.2

**EDIT 2 :** This is the Log I get using the new 3.2 library :

```
07-12 00:02:29.048 28388-28388/com.david.metroztest E/testFragment: details : Native engine initialization failed for unknown reason.
                                                                 stackTrace : java.lang.Throwable
                                                                    at com.nokia.maps.aq.a(EngineError.java:27)
                                                                    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$j.a(MapsEngine.java:731)
                                                                    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$j.a(MapsEngine.java:617)
                                                                    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$j.doInBackground(MapsEngine.java:601)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I really think the problem comes from my device, as this was added in the known issues :

> There is a known issue Android 6.0 that causes the MapOffscreenRenderer to fail on devices that use the Qualcomm 800 chipset, such as the Nexus 5.

My device has a Qualcomm 801 so the problem might come from here

Comment: Are the required permissions for the SDK requested by the application? Android 6.0 target has a new permission model.

Comment: Are all of the permissions required by the HERE SDK requested by the time the initialization function is called? The HERE SDK only supports having all of those permissions at init time, it does not support checking them on demand (i.e. lazy checking). Required permissions can be found [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html#app-simple-android-studio__add-here-sdk-android-studio)

Comment: I request both `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` before initialization because they are *dangerous permissions*, and if these permissions are granted then I launch initialization. But even if I manually turn on permissions in the app's settings, I still get the `UNKNOWN` error from the mapEngine

Comment: @DavidSeroussi did you end up finding a fix for this? I have the exact same issue on my Nexus 5

Answer (score 3):

In latest 3.2 release there is a way to get more detailed info in this case.

You can use:

```
com.here.android.mpa.common.Error.getDetails()
com.here.android.mpa.common.Error.getStackTrace()
```

Example:

```
mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
            if (error == Error.NONE) {
                //
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, error.getDetails());
                Log.e(TAG, error.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried it on my Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 and for me everything works.

Comment: Then I don't understand what is the problem because my code works well on a LG G4 with android 6 ...

Answer (score 0):

We require the following permissions to startup:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Since your application only requested ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE the engine reported the error to you.

Comment: I do require all these permissions. But I also require  the two dangerous permissions at runtime to follow Android 6 guidelines.

Comment: Are there any other possibilities considering what I added in my questions ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was simply that the credentials I was using were demo credentials that had expired. So check that you are using the correct AppId, AppCode and LicenseKey from https://developer.here.com/projects/

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for this issue:

I had to change the disk cache location:

Can read the [documentation here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/map-service.html) to set the disk location to a new location on the device:

```
    boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + ".isolated-here-maps", "com.example.intent");
    if (success) {
        MapEngine.getInstance().init(context, this);
    }
```